# How to create and load in Oracle DB a dynamic table from a csv file

Tags: database, oracle, csv, dynamic, create-table

I would like to create and load a table in Oracle DB from a .csv file.

I am looking for such a way that creates a table in the database with the name of the csv file and as many columns as it requires to fit all the data in the csv. The structure of the table should be created depending on the csv. The csv file could contain rows with different number of fiels.

It is ok if the data types of the columns are VARCHAR2(4000) by default.
No matters the amount of columns the .csv file contains.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Many Thanks,

Comment: I don't think so.  Creating tons of tables on the fly does not sound like a safe thing to do. You would have to first get the metadata about the file in some way.  What application environment will be reading the file?

Comment: Must it be "automated"? Or is there any kind of human intervention possible? If you have Apex installed there is a nice GUI with wizards for that.

Comment: For inserting the data from csv files, SQLLoader (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sql-loader-overview-095816.html) is a great tool. However, you will probably need to script the table creation part yourself.

Comment: It should be "automated". My aim is to visualize in a proper table the discarded rows sent to a bad file via SQLLoader process. The discarded rows are due to too many fields per row in the destiny table.